# PostgreSQL installation and running through terminal

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently installing postgresql to learn about databases. I'm new in this field so please bear with me. I use Windows 7 Home Premium and installed PostgreSQL under C:/. So it went well without errors. Now I want to create database using the cmd. So I write createdb 'databaseName' under C:/PostgreSQL/10/bin. But then it wants a password. I'm trying to type any text but it doesn't let me.

Now I searched for solutions and I'm in a circus right now. In the tutorial I'm watching, the instructor installed postgres using 'brew' and just installed a PostgreSQL GUI. Then he runs psql 'databaseName' to use psql commands.

Do I need to install postgres using 'scoop' in windows? or it is the same thing as using the installer from the web? I really don't know what to do now. I'm sorry if this sounds stupid for some of you :/

btw, I think the instructor uses Git Bash while I use cmd of windows

Comment: It won't show the password you type due to privacy issue but just type the password that you have defined during the installation of posgres SQL

Answer (score -1):

Okay, for windows users who installed PostgreSQL using an installer from web, you don't need to use the cmd instead use the SQL Shell provided by the PostgreSQL itself.